# Authenticate Amazon S3 bucket with C# using AWSSDK.S3

Tags: c#, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

**Edit:-** Need to move some files that are created on Amazon S3 to Azure Blob Storage, I've not used Amazon S3 before and the details that have been provided include a 'path' that I'm not 100% on how to use with the AWSSDK.S3 NuGet package in C#..

So, having never used Amazon S3 before, and an trying to build an azure worker role (or webjob) to watch this storage location and move file or files to Azure Blob storage when they appear - seems fairly easy, but I'm failing at the authentication stage with S3, and the problem is the 'path' variable i have.

I have tested my connection using Cyberduck, and I have the following params:

```
Access Key Id, Secret Access Key, and Path.. the Path is just "folder/folder/"
```

Without the path, I receive an access denied response from Cyberduck... fine, this is expected - but I cannot work out how to embed the path either into the Visual Studio AWS credential manager or in code within a test console harness I've written..

The AWS Explorer, which deals with the credentials only allows me to enter:

```
Access Key Id, Secret Access Key, Account Number ????
```

Do I need to code this all manually? Been reviewing this, but not really had enough time to digest it today:

```
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1310VG2O81PSY/Referencing-Credentials-using-Profiles
```

Cheers,

Ty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

managed to get to some kind of resolution on this in the end, cheers for the down-votes guys :/

in the original post i said that i was trying to navigate to "folder/folder" where the first folder is actually the bucket name (so it turns out) - i'm not an admin on this s3 account so i was going pretty blind into this.

```
string AccessKeyId = "REMOVED";
string SecretAccessKey = "nOt/a+ReAl/kEY";
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey);

AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = "https://folder.s3.amazonaws.com/",
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
};

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds, S3Config);

ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
request.BucketName = "folder";
request.Prefix = "folder/another_folder/";

ListObjectsResponse response = s3Client.ListObjects(request);
foreach (var item in response.S3Objects)
{
    sr.WriteLine(item.Key.ToString());
}
```

Hope this helps someone, still maintain that the SDK doco is awful ;)

I shall put the credentials in the app.config, which I guess is the best practice?

Comment: apparently app.config isn't actually best practice.. it's using a credentials file, but i can't get this to work, so they're going in the app.config basically! :)

Comment: just fyi in the future you can use either Key Vault or Environmental Variables to keep those things out of source code in the future

Comment: This coode save my life tnx a lot

Answer (score -2):

maybe checkout AWS .net SDK? 
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=aws

Since you are running your service on Azure, why not use Azure Blob Storage? 
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Azure+Blob+Storage

Comment: hi, i've checked out the SDK and in my opinion it's quite poorly documented.. i have got it to work, but the details i've been provided i can't see (clearly) how to also add a "path" to the connection credentials

Comment: the goal of what i'm doing is to move files when they appear from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob storage.. so yes i agree with your second point ;)